# iOS: Property not found on object of type

Tags: ios, objective-c, timer, xcode7

```
// First VC prepareForSegue
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"your segue"])
    {
        SecondVC *vc = (SecondVC *)segue.destinationViewController;
       [SecondVC.timer startTimer:nil];
    }
}

// Create Property of  NSTimer *timer
// Second VC's Public Methods
@interface SecondVC ()
{
   NSTimer *_timer;
}

- (void)_timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer;
@end

@implementation SecondVC

- (IBAction)startTimer:(id)sender {
    if (!_timer) {
     _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
                                      target:self
                                    selector:@selector(_timerFired:)
                                    userInfo:nil
                                     repeats:YES];
     }
 }

- (void)_timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer {
     NSLog(@"Timer fired");
}
```

Hi, I want to click a button in viewController(A) and this will trigger a timer in viewController(B). This is the code I have so far however, I keep getting a `"Property 'timer' not found on object of type secondVC "` from this line `[SecondVC.timer startTimer:nil];` Thank you and I have checked that the import statement for the viewController(A) is in viewController(B). How do I resolve this error thanks ?

Comment: my fiurst question is just like your compiler's first question: _where is your property?_ like `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer * timer;`?

Answer (score 0):

Try `[vc startTimer:nil];` instead of `[SecondVC.timer startTimer:nil];` and add the `startTimer:` method to the `SecondVC` interface:

```
@interface SecondVC ()
{
   NSTimer *_timer;
   - (IBAction)startTimer:(id)sender;
}
```

Comment: I get a "No visible @interface for SecondVC declares the selector startTimer "

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the UIViewController object to access the timer, use `[vc startTimer:nil];` instead of `[SecondVC.timer startTimer:nil]`.

Make sure to put `- (IBAction)startTimer:(id)sender` in your header (.h) file, too.

Comment: I get a "No visible @interface for SecondVC declares the selector startTimer "

Answer (score 0):

```
       // First VC prepareForSegue
 -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
        {
             if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"your segue"])
             {
                SecondVC *vc = (SecondVC *)segue.destinationViewController;
                 [vc.timer startTimer:nil];
             }
        }

        //Add below line in  second Vc 's .h file.
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *timer;
     - (void)stopTimer:(id)sender; 
    - (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer; 

        // Second VC's Public Methods
        @interface SecondVC ()
        @end

        @implementation SecondVC

        - (void)startTimer:(id)sender {
            if (!self.timer) {
                self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
                                                          target:self
                                                        selector:@selector(timerFired:)
                                                        userInfo:nil
                                                         repeats:YES];
            }
        }

        - (IBAction)stopTimer:(id)sender {
            if ([self.timer isValid]) {
                [self.timer invalidate];
            }
            self.timer = nil;
        }

        - (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer {
            NSLog(@"Timer fired");
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all you need to declare the `IBAction` in the **Interface** (.h) of `SecondVC`

```
- (IBAction)startTimer:(id)sender;
```

Then call the method on the instance, not on the type

```
[vc startTimer:nil];
```

Comment: -(IBAction)  is not necessary in the interface at this time. He want's to start the timer by tapping a Button in firstVc not in secondVc...

Comment: @Gulliva No, the action is called in secondVC from firstVC via a segue and the declation lines in `Interface` and `Implementation` are supposed to match .

Answer (score -1):

So I think your timer is not a visible Property. Try to set

```
-(void)startTimer;
```

in the SecondViewController.h;
Then use in FirstVc.

```
 SecondVC *vc = (SecondVC *)segue.destinationViewController;
 [vc startTimer];
```

In the SceondVc write this:

```
-(void)startTimer{
    _timer =  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(_timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Comment: There is no method `startTimer:` in `NSTimer`